# Get the Exact match of two text using instr

Tags: vba, excel

How can i match exactly the two texts in `InStr` function ?

Right now my code is like below

```
If InStr(1, arrcallpara(i), strvarcalll) > 0 Then
  blncalling = True
End If
```

arrcallpara(i) contains value "1234" or "12345" or "1234567" and strvarcalll contains "1234567"

The "If" condition should be satisfied only when there is exact match between arrcallpara(i) and strvarcalll.

Comment: [`=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264384%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why use `InStr` ? You can easily check if 2 strings match by using the `=` .

Anyway, let's say that you are somehow forced to use it, I would check first if a string is contained in the second, then if the second is contained in the first. That should do it, but to be totally sure you could also check if the lengths are equal:

```
If InStr(1, arrcallpara(i), strvarcalll) <> 0 And InStr(1, strvarcalll, arrcallpara(i)) <> 0 And Len(arrcallpara(i)) = Len(strvarcalll)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`StrComp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264346%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
If StrComp(arrcallpara(i), strvarcalll) = 0 Then
```

or just plain old [`=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264384%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
If arrcallpara(i) = strvarcalll Then
```

But more than that, your `If` is unnecessary clutter. Just say:

```
blncalling = (arrcallpara(i) = strvarcalll)
```

or

```
blncalling = (StrComp(arrcallpara(i), strvarcalll) = 0)
```

Comment: I have tried strcomp function , but still the if loop is getting failed.

If StrComp(CStr(arrcallpara(i)), CStr(strvarcalll)) = 0 Then
                blncalling = True
               End If

The Values for arrcallpara(i) = "Subscription-Id-Address: 1787663273" & strvarcalll = "Subscription-Id-Address: 1787663273".

Do i have to use any other function to compare the above strings ?

Please help thanks

Comment: I tested your code and couldn't reproduce your issue. The code worked as expected. You will have to give us enough information to reproduce the problem, else we can't help. See this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Jean , Added a watch on the above 2 variables. Found the below result .

For arrcallpara(i) , the value considering as 
"
  Subscription-Id-Address: 1787663273"

and for strvarcalll, the value considering as

"  Subscription-Id-Address: 1787663273"

May i know how can i change arrcallpara(i) from above mentioned style to normal syntax "  Subscription-Id-Address: 1787663273".

Comment: Why are you making this so hard for us? What's the difference between all these strings? Did you consult the link in my previous comment?